# Was there more tension during the cold war or now?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, ukraine, cold-war

I was born shortly after the so called cold war ended. Now we are again with the two giants (Russia and USA) barking at each other. Is it now worse than then?

Comment: How do you define worse? Risk of nuclear war? Anxiety of people? Casualties in wars? Armament race? Probability of total annihilation? Most of these might be difficult next to impossible to estimate.

Comment: Good point. Not sure really what is the best way to define it, if any. Probably some kind of [radar chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart) summary would be interesting. There is probably no single person in the world who can built such chart, probably several people with different backgrounds and experiences are needed.

Comment: Russia isn't the giant anymore that it used to be. It's GDP is smaller than that of South Korea if I remember correctly. All they can do now is attack a smaller neighbor if that one isn't in any alliance. And they can threaten to be irresponsible and use nuclear weapons which is their only big thing. And that's also the only danger, driving Russia into a corner. That basically needs to be avoided. It was a strategic mistake for Russia plus there will be tons of moral guilt but it will take a long time for it to sink in.

Comment: The tensions were/are different for countries throughout the world. Germany more so during the Cold War than now. Ukraine more so now than during the Cold War. Do you have a specific country in mind to narrow the question?

Comment: As somebody who has experienced the Cold War would say tensions are now biger, but this would be an opinion based answer. For fact based one, more details are necesary.

Answer (score 10):

This question isn't really answerable because 'tension' is not well-defined and depends on personal interpretation anyway. Still, we can say that the cold war went through periods of [détente](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9tente) and escalation. Have a look at the most perilous time during the cold war - the [Cuban Missile Crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuban_Missile_Crisis). Briefly, the US deployed missiles to Turkey, and the Soviet Union responded with its own deployment to Cuba (this was also partly because the US had tried and failed to invade Cuba shortly before). The world teetered on the brink of nuclear war, but negotiations successfully defused the situation and both sides withdrew their weapons.

I would argue that the Cuban Missile Crisis was more 'tense' than the current war, which does not pit Russia directly against the US. So we've not hit "peak tension". But it is more tense now than during periods of peak de-escalation. The cold war also featured a lot of proxy conflicts which are at least superficially similar to what's going on right now (Vietnam War, Soviet–Afghan War, Korean War, etc.).

Comment: It should perhaps be mentioned that the [Bay of Pigs invasion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bay_of_Pigs_Invasion), which is presumably what you meant by “US had tried and failed to invade Cuba shortly before”, was – no matter how much it was sposored by the US – at least not officially styled as an act of war nor “special military operation” or something by the US, but rather as a counter-revolutionary act by Cuban exiles. (But that could, of course, be compared to the Russian-speaking separatists in Donetsk and Luhansk.)

Comment: During the Cuban Missile Crisis, the US Strategic Air Command (i.e., the missile- and bomber-based nuclear capabilities) went to DEFCON 2, the highest alert short of a full-out war. "For the only confirmed time in US history, B-52 bombers went on continuous airborne alert, and B-47 medium bombers were dispersed to various military and civilian airfields and made ready to take off, fully equipped, on 15 minutes' notice." ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuban_Missile_Crisis)) I would say tensions are currently *definitely* lower.